# Pythons finding parent directory alternatives

Tags: python, os.path

There seems to be (at least) two different methods of getting a parent directory path in Python, both of which I've seen in common usage. Are the following equivalent or am I missing something?

```
os.path.dirname(my_dir)

os.path.join(my_dir, os.pardir)
```

The former is shorter, but possibly less clear (especially when going up more than 1 layer). I'm struggling to think of any other possible uses for os.pardir or os.path.pardir?

> Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it"

Comment: the obvious way to go up 1 directory would be the first one, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not equivalent.

The difference lies in how paths ending with `os.sep` are handled:

```
>>> os.path.dirname('/foo/bar/')
'/foo/bar'
```

But:

```
>>> os.path.join('/foo/bar/', os.pardir)
'/foo/bar/..'
>>> os.path.abspath('/foo/bar/..')
'/foo'
```

---

So which one should you use? Neither. Use the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('/foo/bar/').parent
PosixPath('/foo')
>>> str(Path('/foo/bar/').parent)
'/foo'
```

If you absolutely cannot use pathlib, stick with `os.path.dirname`. Scenarios where you want to have a pardir segment (`..`) in your file paths are extremely rare and they're more likely to cause problems than anything else.

Comment: It was the trailing slash that had confused me:

`os.path.dirname('/foo/bar/') != os.path.dirname('/foo/bar/')`
where as
`os.path.join('/foo/bar/', os.pardir) ==  os.path.join('/foo/bar', os.pardir)`

I'll try and use pathlib in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following lines. The parent directory is given by the first one (in this case, for html it is /var/www). **os.pardir** shows a '..' which is a constant used almost by most of the Windows and POSIX based OSes to refer a parent directory. When you do a join on it with 'my_dir', you get my_dir + '..' which is not what you might need.

```
>>> import os
>>> a = "/var/www/html"
>>> os.path.dirname(a)
'/var/www'
>>> os.path.join(a, os.pardir)
'/var/www/html/..'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those two things aren't equivalent. If you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) you'll see that `dirname` is just returning the directory of the path your provide.

So `os.path.dirname("/foo/bar/file.txt")` will return `/foo/bar` and `os.path.dirname("/foo/bar/")` will also return `/foo/bar`

As the name suggests, `os.path.join` joins path fragments together.

So if I wanted to get `/foo/bar/file.txt` I could use `os.path.join("/foo/bar/", "file.txt")`. In the example you've given, `os.path.join("/foo/bar/", os.pardir)` would give `/foo/bar/..`.

The other way that does often get used is:

```
parent, _ = os.path.split("/foo/bar/file.txt")
```

Where `parent` is the parent directory, and the value assigned to `_` is `file.txt`. The reason for this is that `split` and `dirname` are doing two slightly different things. `split` is returning the name of the parent directory, and the file name, whereas `dirname` is returning only the first part, and essentially a shorthand method for the line above.

There really aren't a lot of use cases for `pardir`. If you want to see some, check out [this](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/448/os.pardir).